# Outlook email subject only updating after loosing focus

Tags: outlook, vsto

I have a same question as Bryan had in thread  [Outlook 2007 Add-In - subject only updates after losing focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034817/outlook-2007-add-in-subject-only-updates-after-losing-focus)  ... I am using vsto for outlook programming, i am using button controls of outlook ribbon bar on a compose mail window, the button creates a work item from email for tfs, the work item uses subject of an email for its title field.. Now the problem occurs here when i update the subject of an email and clicks the button on Ribbon bar the work item is created with the old value of subject because ribbon button click does not have an effect on Subject focus lost ... I searched alot but found out nothing relevant .. Is there any solution to lost the focus of Email Subject when the button on the ribbon bar clicks??

Answer (score 1):

All Outlook Object Model properties, be that Subject, Recipients, etc. are updated only after the corresponding control loses focus. The only workaround is to use the accessibility API to access the actual control.

Comment: Could you provide a link to info regarding the accessibility API? I've been looking around and I keep finding a disability api for Office.

Comment: I don't have a sample code snippet that I can share, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save mailItem. Smth like mailItem.Save()

If you actually do not want to, then catch mailitem.write event and set boolean cancel, which passed as a reference, to true. Therefore the item will not be saved but subject should be updated.

Comment: Thanks. It's ugly, but this works quite well without resorting to abuse of the accessibility APIs.

Comment: moreover, i got one more hack: you can use sendkeys.sendwait with TAB, then +TAB, and add a sleep after. This will simulate losing focus on field and it will be updated, then focus will return back. Do not know if it is working with subject, but quite a good solution for me to update attendees (as it will call PropertyChanged event). Oh, that is what Dmitry Streblechenko proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SendKey command and send tab in your save/send/write event handler.